# ssl certificate for aws

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a https web app running on my aws ec2 instance.

https://ec2-52-91-100-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

I need to get a ssl certificate for the same so that the scary warnings do not appear.

How can I do this? I tried to buy a ssl from clickssl.com but their helpdesk emailed me with the following:

```
"You completed enrollment process for domain name
ec2-52-91-100-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

I believe you cannot get SSL for this domain name because root domain
name amazonaws.com is Amazon property."
```

If this is the case is there no way to get a ssl certificate for my application? I dont believe thats the case.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

First you need to register a domain through a registrar (e.g. GoDaddy or Amazon Route 53). Next you assign an Elastic IP to your EC2 instance and use your registrar's DNS tool to make your domain point to the Elastic IP address. Then you can request an SSL certificate for your own domain.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to register a domain, or use a subdomain of a domain you already have registered. You do NOT need to use an Elastic IP - they are limited and eventually (if you use multiple domains in your AWS account) you will run out. Instead, you can use a CNAME to point to the AWS name (e.g., ec2-52-91-100-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com).

Once you have that set, use Let's Encrypt to get a free widely accepted certificate. There are plenty of tutorials on the installation process - try:
https://ivopetkov.com/b/let-s-encrypt-on-ec2/

Just noticed the original question is OLD - which means (among other things) that Let's Encrypt wasn't even an option at the time. But for anyone who stumbles across this question now, it is a great solution.