# ssl for aws EC2 Flask application

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

I have registered a free domain name from freenom.com and added nameservers from AWS route53. Now my domain `<blabla>.ga` successfully redirects to EC2 python flask server. But I really can't figure out how to add ssl by using lets encrypt. I am following the link https://ivopetkov.com/b/let-s-encrypt-on-ec2/ for SLLifying my ec2.after running letsencrypt-auto I add domain names and press enter, then I get

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-218 letsencrypt]$ cd /opt/letsencrypt/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-218 letsencrypt]$ ./letsencrypt-auto
Requesting to rerun ./letsencrypt-auto with root privileges...
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
No names were found in your configuration files. Please enter in your domain
name(s) (comma and/or space separated)  (Enter 'c' to cancel): iotserver.ga  www.iotserver.ga
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for iotserver.ga
http-01 challenge for www.iotserver.ga
Cleaning up challenges
Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.
```

A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636975/ssl-certificate-for-aws), but I've already done most part explained in both of the answers. Can anyone assist me on what I am missing here ?

Comment: This may help: https://medium.com/@nipunr/free-ssl-aws-route53-acm-188ae3f66fed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following tutorials:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Make sure that you able to access said web app without https, then try to install SSL. As I can see you are getting following error

> Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.

There must be some configuration issue. Please debug it and let me know.

Comment: These tutorials were smooth. finally got the HTTPS. Thanks :)